# To create a sidebar hidden in the left hand side of a view like dolphin browser do

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to have this android layout basically works like the dolphin browser, which I can make my sidebar in the left appears while scrolling the view horizontally to the right.

I figure it could be for example two sliding drawer working together, but after tying, it doesn't work out.

So, any thought or any reference and tutorial will be really nice!

[Here](http://bestmobileapp.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Dolphin-Browser-HD-Android.jpg) is the screen shot which can illustrate how this layout works(I'm totally new here, so no picture upload allowed)

Comment: I'm also interested in this, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a HorizontalScrollView, and a tableview within it.

Put the menu in the left cell of the tableview, and the rest in the right cell.

Comment: yes, it works, but not exactly the way i need, for the horizontal scroll, i would like it have it like the android home screen, meaning i just have to fling the screen, and the view will automatic go to the right position